# Проблема с базой данных

Tags: android, кодировка, mysql

У меня есть база на хостинге. Есть на сервере апи, которое взаимодействует с базой и с приложением. Я отправляю гет запрос получаю `json` потом его парсю. Если я ввожу элементы базы вручную, то база работает нормально и в приложении высвечиваются нужные мне поля, но если я копипастю в базу из каких то сайтов или даже с текствого редактора, то почему то в приложении оно мне выдает вместо строк `null` постоянно. Я не понимаю почему. в `phpmyadmin` в графе "сравнение" показывает кодировку `utf8_general_ci`, я в `notepad++` делаю кодировку `utf8`, но это не помогает. я вообще не понимаю в чем тут проблема может быть.
Поля у меня типа `TEXT`

вот php апи:

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will get single product details
 * A product is identified by product id (pid)
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// check for post data
if (isset($_GET["pid"])) {
    $pid = $_GET['pid'];

    // get a product from products table
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM testimonies WHERE pid = $pid");

    if (!empty($result)) {
        // check for empty result
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

            $product = array();
            $product["pid"] = $result["pid"];
            $product["name"] = $result["name"];
            $product["text_t"] = $result["text_t"];
            // success
            $response["success"] = 1;

            // user node
            $response["product"] = array();

            array_push($response["product"], $product);

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // no product found
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No product found";

            // echo no users JSON
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else {
        // no product found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No product found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

а вот как я получаю json

```
package com.model;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала надо понять следующе: 
utf8 это кодировка
utf8_general_ci - метод сравнения слов и букв на основании языковых особенностей. 
Для каждого текстового поля как раз и создается такое "сравнение".

Т.е. если вы в phpmyadmin добавите данные они должны добавится обязательно - это не влияет на содержание данных, а только на параметры выборки.

Для добавления из самого приложения нужно указать кодировку подключения т.е.

SET NAMES UTF-8

Эту строку надо послать после подключения к базе данных приложением.

Что касается выборок вы их нам не предоставили потому думать и понимать что вы куда добавляете не совсем понятно.

И еще одно потом его парсю!!! Не совсем понятно как вы кодируете json и каким образом вы его у себя потом показываете. Возможно проблема не в выборке а скажем в неэкранированых кавычках или еще чем то подобном.

Comment: я добавил кода в свой вопрос

Comment: exception не вылетает. json нормально распознается, я даже дебажил,и смотрел текущие значение, вроде нормально. Если я пишу вручную текст при добавлении в значений в базу через phpmyadmin то в приложение этот текст виден, а если копирую текст, то в phpmyadmin он нормально отображается, а в приложении null

Comment: Как бы явно ничего не вяжется, почему BufferedReader  получаем в iso-8859-1

Логично что эти данные не в UTF и они там вообще должны типа буковками D отображатся.

И вот когда 

$db = new DB_CONNECT();


тогда и надо еще 

mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

Comment: огромное спасибо) сработало. я не учил никогда пхп. Тот код не мой. Сейчас уже дописываю приложение. Осталось сделать напоминальщик который будет срабатывать каждый день(пользователь задает во сколько). я понимаю что иногда мои вопросы для многих выглядят глупыми и простыми, но все-равно процесс идет, приложение пишется, хоть и медленно. Потом еще придется рефакторинг кода делать потому, что обнаружил неправильное и глупое использование ресурсов, дублирование код и так далее.

Answer (score 0):

```
htaccess AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Comment: у меня уже стоит на сервере UTF-8 дефолтом, а в чем еще может быть проблема?

Comment: если в htaccess не прописано - пропиши. Не важно что там у тебя дефолтом стоит

Comment: сделал как вы сказали добавил в корень там где лежит сайт .htaccess и в файле добавил строчку AddDefaultCharset utf-8, но ничего не изменилось. не знаю в чем дело